# Three JS: Is vertex displacement via textures limited to 256 values?

Tags: three.js, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm rendering the following texture to a [WebGLRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) in ThreeJS using [Ashima's GLSL noise](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise):

[image]

I'm then reading the texture's RGB channels to displace several meshes' vertices in the XYZ axes with the following GLSL code:

```
vec4 fluctuation = texture2D(fluxTexture, uv);
curPos.y += (fluctuation.r - 0.5) * 40.0;
curPos.x += (fluctuation.g - 0.5) * 20.0;
curPos.z += (fluctuation.b - 0.5) * 20.0;
```

However, since the movement is very subtle, I've noticed that the vertices jump a few pixels for every step when the RGB values change. I'm attributing this artifact to each color's limitation to 256 values apiece. Is there any way to change the texture's bit depth to 16 or 32 bits so I can get more precision out of the RGB channels?

Comment: There is of course, you should post your code regarding the creation of the webgl target. You can also encode other precision in an 8 bit texture or multiple 8 bit textures. Three has that pack/unpack method in the shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in the type property of a render target:

[Textures](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Textures)

You can try THREE.FloatType.

```
// Test for iOS devices, because they don't support THREE.FloatType
var dataType = (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? THREE.HalfFloatType : THREE.FloatType;

this.renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(50, 50, {
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    type: dataType,
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up stumbling upon this answer, but didn't fully settle for it because THREE.FloatType doesn't work on iOS for some reason, and the doc says only `UnsignedByteType`, `UnsignedShort4444Type` or `THREE.UnsignedShort5551Type` are allowed. Do you know why that is? Is that a documentation issue?

Comment: Weird, i'm not sure i could have sworn that i had it working on iOS. You can try something like this to encode it into 8 bits:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/acdda10d5896aa10abdf33e971951dbf7bd8f074/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/packing.glsl#L17